# How to change padding on cells within a DataGrid - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, padding

I am trying to add padding to all of the cells within my `DataGrid` (not `DataGridView`).  I want there to be space between the walls of the cell and the text within the cells. Is there any way to do this?  I have looked into this and all I see is how to do it with `DataGridView` and not `DataGrid`...

Here is a picture of the `DataGrid` with no padding: [image: No Padding within cells]

Notice how the the text is pushed tight to the line on the right side.

Please help!  Thank you!

Comment: @Plutonix I thought that `DefaultCellStyle` was only a property of `DataGridView` not `DataGrid`?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your `DataGrid (not DataGridView)` as the other way round.

Comment: Is the a WinForm DataGrid?

Comment: @TnTinMn Yes, I believe so.  Sorry, I am still relatively new to coding.  The namespace is: `System.Web.UI.WebControls`.

Comment: That is a WebForm control then.  Set the `CellPadding` property on the DataGrid.

Comment: @TnTinMn, I did try setting the `CellPadding` property on the `DataGrid` but no luck.  I posted an answer below that ended up working for me.Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

I created a CSS file and added left and right padding to `td`:

```
td {
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
}
```

I then added a reference to that CSS file into the same markup file where my `DataGrid` is located:

```
<link href="YourFolderNameHere/YourCSSFileNameHere.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I did try what @TnTinMn suggested in his comment with `CellPadding` but had no luck.

**NOTE:**  I am unsure if this method will work in all cases or only in my own.  By doing this all `td` elements will take this style, which in my case is fine because I wanted all `td` elements within every table to have this padding style.